# media monks crawler, blacklist

Tags: regex, web-crawler

I'm using MediaMonks crawler to crawl some websites.
[Packagist link](https://packagist.org/packages/mediamonks/crawler)

There is a function called blacklist, and I'd like to use that to avoid crawling all url's that has hashtags in them.

Something like this:

```
// TODO: Write the correct regular expression.
$crawler->addBlacklistUrlMatcher(new Matcher\PathRegexUrlMatcher('/#/'));
```

I'm really bad with regular expressions, can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

It probably depends on how blacklist matcher works, but in general case if you want to catch the whole line containing `#` symbol in it, this is what you need to put into brackets:

```
.*\#.*
```

This will catch **whole** line(s) containing `#` symbol, for instance:

```
#somehashtag
#some hash tag
```

This site will help you to create regex for your needs: https://regex101.com

Comment: Hi, thanks. How do I figure out how the matcher works, it throws " Unknown modifier '*' "

Here is an example on white list that works:
$crawler->addWhitelistUrlMatcher(new Matcher\PathRegexUrlMatcher('~^/stuff~'));

That whitelists all urls that has "stuff" in them...

Comment: Oh, I see that the regEx works just fine, but the url that is checked by the crawler has cut off the # part, but it still goes through the same url numerous because of the #'s - but when doing preg_match the url string does not have the # in it... I'll need to investigate a bit.